# How can I set a VIM filetype programmatically?

Tags: vim

Is there a way to set a vim filetype programmatically, so instead of doing something like this:

```
au BufNewFile,BufRead *.dump set filetype=sql
```

I can do something like this

```
let g:temp_file_type = 'sql'
au BufNewFile,BufRead *.dump set filetype= g:temp_file_type
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can set options with let by prefixing the option name with `&`. eg:

```
let &filetype=g:temp_file_type
```

Comment: thank you!  "au BufNewFile,BufRead *.dump let &filetype=g:temp_file_type"    worked perfectly

Answer (score 1):

put `au BufNewFile,BufRead *.dump set filetype=sql` into your `filetype.vim`